# ATG-Endeca indexing error for autogen dimension

Tags: oracle, indexing, dimensions, atg, endeca

ATG-Endeca CAS deployment with migrated dimension value ids between environments using cas-cmd API. If the ids haven't been imported indexing completes ok. Otherwise the following error occurs:

> Caused by:
>   com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.CasControlException: Crawl
>   'app-last-mile-crawl' failed with error: Dimension value
>   records cannot be specified for autogen dimensions. Received dimension
>   value record with spec 'r8-16' for dimension 'product.sizeRange'

Per my understanding when in the ids, exported from environment A, there are dimension value ids for an autogen dimension but when the A-ids are imported in to environment B and the B-indexing is triggered the error occurs.

Also the error seems more frequent for dimension that have configuration in index_config.json, ie range dimensions.

Any ideas on how is this resolved or a confirmation of the cause would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Range Dimension can not be auto dimension and this needs to be available in index-config.json or dimension mapping csv file. Migrate index-config from one env to other with all range dimensions configured with same id.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal

Comment: Hi Ajay. Thanks for your answer. Yes, the issue was that this range dimension had definition in multiple ouput-config.xml files (atg-endeca application) and in a couple of them was set as auto generated.